# Binding dataContext/viewModel on ContextMenu MenuItem in itemContainerStyle Setter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

I have a listview, that contains multiple child items. I wana to display ContextMenu on rightclick item in that listview.

Actualy i have two menuItems that can call command on certain items, but also i wana to call commands from viewModel.

In example below is my definition of context menu. First two MenuItems call commands directly on ListViewItem and on third im trying to call command from ViewModel assigned to DataContext of user control.

```
 <ListView x:Name="snapshotList" ItemsSource="{Binding SnapshotList}" SelectedItem="{Binding ItemSelected}"  Margin="10,81,10,27" MinHeight="100">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle >
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">                    
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Copy path" Command="{Binding CopyPathCommand}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Copy path (cmd)" Command="{Binding CopyPathCommandToCmdCommand}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Test" Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I found many similar questions where people claimed that ContextMenu isnt in generalTree co it cant access viewModel/DataContext directly and is necessary to pass it via Tag/Placement target. But when i tried that i always get error in output. So how can i pass dataContext/ViewModel of user control to ContextMenu -> menuItem?

```
**System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'PlacementTarget' property not found on 'object' ''MenuItem' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext; DataItem='MenuItem' (Name=''); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')**
```

Edit3:
Okay so i think i found solution. I had a mistake in traversing xmlTree and if i followed @clemens hints i found this

```
<ListView x:Name="snapshotList"  ItemsSource="{Binding SnapshotList}" SelectedItem="{Binding ItemSelected}"  Margin="10,81,10,27" MinHeight="100" >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>                
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" >
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=userControl}"/>
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Copy path" Command="{Binding CopyPathCommand}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Copy path (cmd)" Command="{Binding CopyPathCommandToCmdCommand}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Test" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.TestCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Which is working and im understading it in this way: 
- from MenuItem i cannot access ListView as PlacementTarget and placement target returns ListViewItem
- So i binded DataContext of UserControl to tag of ListView item
- then in MenuItem i get relativeAncestor ContextMenu (only one i can access) and then took his PlacementTarget (which is ListViewItem) and get his tag and call command on it

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. In contrast to ContextMenu, MenuItem does not have a PlacementTarget property. Try `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}`.

Comment: @Clemens yep, that parialy working, i can access ContextMenu, but context menu still do not have correct DataContext. And if i try to access ListView (which have correct DataContext) its unaccessible.

Comment: Did you try `ElementName=snapshotList` instead of RelativeSource?

Comment: @Clemens thanks for efforts, i tried what you suggested, i think that i partialy understand it, but still im without success. But i found another way to solve my problem (hope it do not have some disadvantages/issues) and i edited it into question

Comment: Note that this will create *another* instance of your view model class. It will certainly not work as you expect.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for advices i think i figured it out (edited in asnwer) and probably it will help someone in future